# Clicking a Bootstrap JavaScript Radio Button Using Selenium in Python

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap, selenium

### Question

What's the proper way to click on a radio button created using Bootstrap's JavaScript Button when running the browser via Selenium?

### Background

I'm developing a WebApp using [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com) v1.7 and [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) v3.2.0 with functional tests performed using [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org). Some HTML pages have radio buttons created using [Bootstrap's JavaScript buttons](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons).

```html
<form class="form-horizontal well" role="form" method="POST">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" data-toggle="buttons">
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="selected_test" value="loop_on_failure"
          id="id_loop_on_failure" />Loop on Failure
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="selected_test" value="test_until_failure"
          id="id_test_until_failure" />Test Until Failure
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" autofocus name="serial_number"
          id="id_serial_number" placeholder="Enter Serial Number">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" id="id_run_test" type="submit">
            Test Board
          </button>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

I am able to select the desired radio button, enter a S/N, and press the "Test Board" button when running via Django's `manage.py runserver`. However, when I run a functional test such as the following, I get an error. More specifically, the POST data doesn't contain the `selected_test` key, which leads me to believe the radio button isn't actually being clicked by Selenium.

```python
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.find_element_by_id('id_test_until_failure').click()
self.assertTrue(browser.find_element_by_id(
    'id_test_until_failure').is_selected())
```

Answer (score 0):

By switching the Selenium webdriver from Firefox to Chrome, I was tipped off that Selenium needs to actually click on the parent of the input tag. I believe this is due to the input tag being wrapped inside of the label tags, but I'm not certain of that.

Given I have an id on the input tag, the easiest way I found to do this was as follows:

```python
browser.find_element_by_id(
    'id_test_until_failure').find_element_by_xpath('..').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have the two radio buttons in a page, with the name gender and values ‘F’ and ‘M’. You should use the choose method the following way:

```
browser.choose('gender', 'F')
```